# Bitwise OR operator in Asm api version definition

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I was going through the source code of asm  and found following definition

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jodd/jodd-proxetta/3.5.2/jodd/asm5/Opcodes.java

```
int ASM4 = 4 << 16 | 0 << 8 | 0;
```

Could anyone please explain why bitwise OR is needed?
why just `int ASM4 = 4`?

Answer (score 4):

The value isn't 4; it's 262144. Presumably they write it that way because they are thinking of it as a three-part number 4.0.0 with each part occupying one byte. If they wrote `int ASM4 = 262144;` that wouldn't be clear to the reader. The expression is evaluated at compile time so there's no run-time cost.